# How to modify and add words sequentially in a list - Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, format

I don't know if this is possible as I'm a newbie to Python, but I wanted to create a list that has a sequential order to it. So I have two lists as follows:

```
stock_list = ['MSFT', 'YHOO']
ret = [0, 1, 2, 3]

returns = ["ret{}".format(*ret) for ret in enumerate(ret)]
```

returns

```
['ret0', 'ret1', 'ret2', 'ret3']
```

From the above lists of returns and stock_list, I can create the following:

```
for index, ret_stock in enumerate(returns):
    returns[index] += "_MSFT"
returns
```

Output:

```
['ret0_MSFT', 'ret1_MSFT', 'ret2_MSFT', 'ret3_MSFT']
```

Ideally, what I'm trying to get is this using the stock_list for both tickers, MSFT and YHOO:

```
  ['ret0_MSFT', 'ret1_MSFT', 'ret2_MSFT', 'ret3_MSFT', 
       'ret0_YHOO', 'ret1_YHOO', 'ret2_YHOO', 'ret3_YHOO']
```

So, I could do the previous method with enumerate, but that would become increasingly time consuming if, say instead of just two tickers, MSFT and YHOO, I had 100.

By creating a list of say, 100 or more tickers, and applying it to a list of returns such as this one already shown.

```
['ret0', 'ret1', 'ret2', 'ret3']
```

Is it possible? Maybe I'm asking the wrong question or approaching from the wrong angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not looping through the stock_list items.. just add another loop.

This code will:

1. `for` each stock in stock_list
2. from 1 to the defined `range` of tickers (100 in the example), do the following:

   2.1 create string `s` that `concatenates` the prefix with the `stock` name

   2.2 `append` string `s` to `stock_list_v2`

*obs.: you don't have to use `ret = [0, 1, 2, 3]`, just define a `range()`.*

**Code:**

```
stock_list = ['MSFT', 'YHOO'] 
stock_list_v2 = []

for stock in stock_list:
    for i in range(101):
        s = 'ret' + str(i) + '_' + stock
        stock_list_v2.append(s)
```

**Output:**

```
['ret0_MSFT', 'ret1_MSFT', 'ret2_MSFT', 'ret3_MSFT', 'ret4_MSFT', 'ret5_MSFT', 'ret6_MSFT', 'ret7_MSFT', 'ret8_MSFT', 'ret9_MSFT', 'ret10_MSFT', 'ret11_MSFT', 'ret12_MSFT', 'ret13_MSFT', 'ret14_MSFT', 'ret15_MSFT', 'ret16_MSFT', 'ret17_MSFT', 'ret18_MSFT', 'ret19_MSFT', 'ret20_MSFT', 'ret21_MSFT', 'ret22_MSFT', 'ret23_MSFT', 'ret24_MSFT', 'ret25_MSFT', 'ret26_MSFT', 'ret27_MSFT', 'ret28_MSFT', 'ret29_MSFT', 'ret30_MSFT', 'ret31_MSFT', 'ret32_MSFT', 'ret33_MSFT', 'ret34_MSFT', 'ret35_MSFT', 'ret36_MSFT', 'ret37_MSFT', 'ret38_MSFT', 'ret39_MSFT', 'ret40_MSFT', 'ret41_MSFT', 'ret42_MSFT', 'ret43_MSFT', 'ret44_MSFT', 'ret45_MSFT', 'ret46_MSFT', 'ret47_MSFT', 'ret48_MSFT', 'ret49_MSFT', 'ret50_MSFT', 'ret51_MSFT', 'ret52_MSFT', 'ret53_MSFT', 'ret54_MSFT', 'ret55_MSFT', 'ret56_MSFT', 'ret57_MSFT', 'ret58_MSFT', 'ret59_MSFT', 'ret60_MSFT', 'ret61_MSFT', 'ret62_MSFT', 'ret63_MSFT', 'ret64_MSFT', 'ret65_MSFT', 'ret66_MSFT', 'ret67_MSFT', 'ret68_MSFT', 'ret69_MSFT', 'ret70_MSFT', 'ret71_MSFT', 'ret72_MSFT', 'ret73_MSFT', 'ret74_MSFT', 'ret75_MSFT', 'ret76_MSFT', 'ret77_MSFT', 'ret78_MSFT', 'ret79_MSFT', 'ret80_MSFT', 'ret81_MSFT', 'ret82_MSFT', 'ret83_MSFT', 'ret84_MSFT', 'ret85_MSFT', 'ret86_MSFT', 'ret87_MSFT', 'ret88_MSFT', 'ret89_MSFT', 'ret90_MSFT', 'ret91_MSFT', 'ret92_MSFT', 'ret93_MSFT', 'ret94_MSFT', 'ret95_MSFT', 'ret96_MSFT', 'ret97_MSFT', 'ret98_MSFT', 'ret99_MSFT', 'ret100_MSFT', 'ret0_YHOO', 'ret1_YHOO', 'ret2_YHOO', 'ret3_YHOO', 'ret4_YHOO', 'ret5_YHOO', 'ret6_YHOO', 'ret7_YHOO', 'ret8_YHOO', 'ret9_YHOO', 'ret10_YHOO', 'ret11_YHOO', 'ret12_YHOO', 'ret13_YHOO', 'ret14_YHOO', 'ret15_YHOO', 'ret16_YHOO', 'ret17_YHOO', 'ret18_YHOO', 'ret19_YHOO', 'ret20_YHOO', 'ret21_YHOO', 'ret22_YHOO', 'ret23_YHOO', 'ret24_YHOO', 'ret25_YHOO', 'ret26_YHOO', 'ret27_YHOO', 'ret28_YHOO', 'ret29_YHOO', 'ret30_YHOO', 'ret31_YHOO', 'ret32_YHOO', 'ret33_YHOO', 'ret34_YHOO', 'ret35_YHOO', 'ret36_YHOO', 'ret37_YHOO', 'ret38_YHOO', 'ret39_YHOO', 'ret40_YHOO', 'ret41_YHOO', 'ret42_YHOO', 'ret43_YHOO', 'ret44_YHOO', 'ret45_YHOO', 'ret46_YHOO', 'ret47_YHOO', 'ret48_YHOO', 'ret49_YHOO', 'ret50_YHOO', 'ret51_YHOO', 'ret52_YHOO', 'ret53_YHOO', 'ret54_YHOO', 'ret55_YHOO', 'ret56_YHOO', 'ret57_YHOO', 'ret58_YHOO', 'ret59_YHOO', 'ret60_YHOO', 'ret61_YHOO', 'ret62_YHOO', 'ret63_YHOO', 'ret64_YHOO', 'ret65_YHOO', 'ret66_YHOO', 'ret67_YHOO', 'ret68_YHOO', 'ret69_YHOO', 'ret70_YHOO', 'ret71_YHOO', 'ret72_YHOO', 'ret73_YHOO', 'ret74_YHOO', 'ret75_YHOO', 'ret76_YHOO', 'ret77_YHOO', 'ret78_YHOO', 'ret79_YHOO', 'ret80_YHOO', 'ret81_YHOO', 'ret82_YHOO', 'ret83_YHOO', 'ret84_YHOO', 'ret85_YHOO', 'ret86_YHOO', 'ret87_YHOO', 'ret88_YHOO', 'ret89_YHOO', 'ret90_YHOO', 'ret91_YHOO', 'ret92_YHOO', 'ret93_YHOO', 'ret94_YHOO', 'ret95_YHOO', 'ret96_YHOO', 'ret97_YHOO', 'ret98_YHOO', 'ret99_YHOO', 'ret100_YHOO']
```

**p.s.:** you'll gain time if you transform this loop in a `list comprehension`.

```
stock_list_v2 = ['ret' + str(i) + '_' + stock for i in range(101) for stock in stock_list]
```

Comment: Wow, awesome! Thanks dot.Py! :)

Answer (score 4):

Put your current code in another loop. You can even create it within the comprehension:

```
>>> stock_list = ['MSFT', 'YHOO']
>>> ret = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> returns = ["ret{}_{}".format(r, stk) for stk in stock_list for r in ret]
>>> returns
['ret0_MSFT', 'ret1_MSFT', 'ret2_MSFT', 'ret3_MSFT', 'ret0_YHOO', 'ret1_YHOO', 'ret2_YHOO', 'ret3_YHOO']
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, maybe this approach would work.

```
stock_list = ['MSFT', 'YHOO']
rets = range(4)

for stock in stock_list:
    stock_returns = ['ret{}_{}'.format(ret, stock) for ret in rets]
```

This way, for every stock on your list, you will create a new separated list with the order you want.